# How to get a value from strings.xml in a retrofit interface?

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit

We're using retrofit android client (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) for network calls to our server and I cant figure out how to access values in the `strings.xml` file from the interface class that we created for retrofit.

Here's a small sample of our interface code.

```
//all retrofit imports
public interface APIService {

    String API_KEY = "XXXX"; //Get this value from strings.xml

    @GET("/api/getNames?api_key=" + API_KEY)
    public ArrayList<String> getNames();
}
```

Right now *XXXX* is hardcoded but we want it to get taken from `strings.xml`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the API_KEY as a parameter using

```
   @GET("/api/getNames")
   public ArrayList<String> getNames(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

Check URL manipulation section [URL Manipulation - Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I was thinking about that too but would require to rewrite the parts of the app that make the call. Was hoping there was a direct way to get it from the interface?

Comment: If you are storing the API_KEY in the settings is because maybe it could change someday in that order you need a way where always you are passing the current value of the string. So If you don't have a lot of parts to rewrite I suggest you to create a static method that could access the value from the strings.xml.

Comment: yah this will work, we have other calls being made through URL manipulation so this should work too. Thanks